# HTTP Archive (HAR) TOTAL response size of zero

Tags: har

According to [HAR 1.2 specification](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/#response), the response size is calculated as:

```
var totalSize = entry.response.headersSize + entry.response.bodySize;
```

But how could the response size be zero (`=1273+(-1273)`), for example in the following HAR:

```
"response": {
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "content": {
       "size": 4916,
       "mimeType": "application/x-javascript",
       "compression": 6189
    },
    "headersSize": 1273,
    "bodySize": -1273
```

In the specification, there is no negetive value for bodySize other than `-1`:

> bodySize [number] - Size of the received response body in bytes. Set to zero in case of  responses coming from the cache (304). Set to -1 if the info is not available.

Comment: How could you possibly get a negative body size in the first place?

Comment: I trying to find out this. It happens regularly in my HARs. I use chrome v31 with "Preserve Log on Page Navigation" turned on in Network section.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug on Chromium. There were similar one, in timings section, in the past: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152201

You may [open a issue about this one](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues).